# How to make bootstrap thumbnail caurosel responsive?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsiveness

Hello i am trying to make a slider using bootstrap(thumbnail slider) and it is sliding but i want to slide one by one column (like first column: 1-2-3, second: 2-3-4, third: 3-4-1 and so on) but don't know where i am misleading, please help me out to make it.
hints:
in initial it will show column: 1-2-3
then when i click right control it the column:1 should be hidden and column: 2 should shift to first place and column: 3rd to center and column:4 should show at last.

**Hello guyz my problem is solved but how i can make it responsive please help me.**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myCarousel').carousel({
    interval: 10000
  })
  $('.fdi-Carousel .item').each(function() {
    var next = $(this).next();
    if (!next.length) {
      next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }
    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

    if (next.next().length > 0) {
      next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    } else {
      $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.carousel-inner.onebyone-carosel {
  margin: auto;
  width: 90%;
}

.onebyone-carosel .active.left {
  left: -33.33%;
}

.onebyone-carosel .active.right {
  left: 33.33%;
}

.onebyone-carosel .next {
  left: 33.33%;
}

.onebyone-carosel .prev {
  left: -33.33%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span12">
      <div class="well">
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel fdi-Carousel slide">
          <!-- Carousel items -->
          <div class="carousel fdi-Carousel slide" id="eventCarousel" data-interval="0">
            <div class="carousel-inner onebyone-carosel">
              <div class="item active">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" class="img-responsive center-block"></a>
                  <div class="text-center">1</div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" class="img-responsive center-block"></a>
                  <div class="text-center">2</div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" class="img-responsive center-block"></a>
                  <div class="text-center">3</div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" class="img-responsive center-block"></a>
                  <div class="text-center">4</div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" class="img-responsive center-block"></a>
                  <div class="text-center">5</div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" class="img-responsive center-block"></a>
                  <div class="text-center">6</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#eventCarousel" data-slide="prev"></a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#eventCarousel" data-slide="next"></a>
          </div>
          <!--/carousel-inner-->
        </div>
        <!--/myCarousel-->
      </div>
      <!--/well-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Make it a snippet (CTRL+M) in post editor so that we can run it and see it visually. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @ProEvilz i formated, may be this will help to understand. please help me out.

Comment: so... you want to slide in groups of 3 images?

Comment: @ProEvilz yes 3 or 4 no matters but it should be responsive.